# How can vscode stop send error notifications?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am doing leetcode exercises on vscode, using this extension:

[image]

However vscode keeps sending error notifications about the golang codes written locally lack of main module

[image]

How can I disable vscode error notifications? As those golang codes are used to run remotely, so there are no needs to compile locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if you can [disable the Go extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_disable-an-extension), just for your current (leetcode) workspace.

> If you don't want to permanently remove an extension, you can instead temporarily disable the extension by clicking the gear button at the right of an extension entry.
> You can disable an extension globally or just for your current Workspace.
> You will be prompted to reload VS Code after you disable an extension.

By disabling it just for the workspace, you can still use Go for Go projects in a separate workspace in the same VSCode.

Comment: This solution works, although I have to write Golang code like plain text without any code recommendations

Comment: @YellowHuan OK. That seems an issue to be reported to https://github.com/LeetCode-OpenSource/vscode-leetcode/issues, as the workaround I propose above is not very practical.